# SSIS package from sql agent failed csv

Tags: csv, ssis

I have sql server agent job that runs the SSIS package which loads the csv file to sql server destionation. All these days it was working fine but now I am getting the below error message.

There is no change in the package and file was not opened while running the job and also security looks fine.

the same works when I execute the package in dev environment but getting failed when I execute the same package as job in prod environment.

Thanks for all your suggestions/help.
[image]

Comment: My guess would be to check the text file encoding (Ansi, UTF-8, LE BOM etc), maybe that changed in the latest file? Although you said you tried the *exact same file* on the dev environment? Or maybe a copy&paste mistake from the dev SSIS to production SSIS, I mean the ConnectionString contains the correct full path as it exists on the production server? idk SSIS is famous for its unhelpful error messages...

Comment: I just updated few columns in csv file like every month I used to do. It just use to run without any issue. If I use the dev copy then also it is failing .. :)

Comment: Then most likely it's due to something in the new data. Like maybe using a comma decimal instead of a dot. Or a text value contains a double quote `"` character which isn't closed properly. Or the column datatypes are interpreted differently, due to the new data. Something like that.

Comment: There was some issue with shared location. I replaced the shared location with the IP address and was able to load the data.